# Cannot add custom SSL certificate in AppEngine dash

Tags: google-app-engine

I've followed [the instructions provided in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate) to the letter with no luck. I receive **Error - The SSL certificate provided could not be inserted.** without any additional message as to why.

Looking under the hood, the console sends a POST request which comes back with a status 400 and the following JSON:

```
{"code":1,"errorSpace":"domains","status":400,"message":"1"}
```

For Google folks here, the above might mean something.

Comment: Left it for few hours, and now it works.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error... will try again later

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. Worked for www. but not for the naked domain

Answer (score 1):

In my case, re-ordering the concatenated certificates in this order solved it:

- domain cert
- intermediate cert
- ca cert

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my case error was caused by too long RSA private key. Retrying with certificate generated with 2048 key solved the issue.